# Why Automapper needs IMapper interface for map?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper

I have created an extension to map my types that implemented `IHaveStandardMapping` interface.

```
public static class AutomapperExtensions
{
    public static TDest MapTo<TDest>(this object src, IMapper mapper) 
        where TDest: IHaveStandardMapping
    {
        return (TDest)mapper.Map(src, src.GetType(), typeof(TDest));
    }
}
```

And I am using it in my service.

```
public class ComponentService : IComponentService
{
    private readonly PostgresqlDataContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ComponentService(PostgresqlDataContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<ComponentViewModel> GetComponent(string id)
    {
        var existing = await _context.Components.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);

        if (existing == null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Component");

        var result = existing.MapTo<ComponentViewModel>(_mapper);

        return result;
    }
}
```

But I need to get `IMapper` interface for all services.

I should use it in method

```
existing.MapTo<T>(_mapper);
```

The old versions were did not need the `IMapper` interface.

Is there a short way without using `IMapper`?

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. Did you use the static API which was removed in version 9?

Answer (score 1):

The static API is now deprecated. IMapper is used so you can inject the mapper in your controllers/services. I you want to you can create your own service wrapping the IMapper interface, so you can limit your dependency on the IMapper interface to one service only.